# Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response when using http get req from JS to SlackAPI

Tags: javascript, http, next.js, cors, slack-api

I understand that there are many similar questions, but I am posting this because I feel it is slightly different.

I am trying to send a GET request to the Slack API using an HTTP request.
Specifically, the code looks like the following.

```js
import useSWR from "swr";

const useSlackSearch = (query: string) => {
  const token = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SLACK_API_USER_TOKEN;
  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

  const slackURL = `https://slack.com/api/search.messages?query=${query}`;

  const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: myHeaders,
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    return response;
  };

  const { data, error } = useSWR(slackURL, fetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: true,
    revalidateOnReconnect: true,
  });

  if (error) {
    return console.log(`Failed to load: ${error}`);
  } else if (!data) {
    return console.log("Loading...");
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
};

export default useSlackSearch;
```

The environments I'm using are as follows.

- Device: MacBook Air
- OS: macOS
- Browser: Chrome
- From: localhost:3000
- To: Slack API html page (https://slack.com/api/search.messages)

After reading the MDN articles like below, I understood that

- There is such a thing as a simple HTTP request as defined by MDN
- If the request you want to send does not correspond to this simple request, the browser will send a preflight request
- In the response to that preflight request, there is a header called Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
- Only headers set to the value of this Access-Control-Allow-Headers header can be used as headers in the main request after preflighting.
- In this case, I tried to use the Authorization header, but it was trapped by the above restriction.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

That's all I understand.
However, on the official Slack API page for the method in question, it says to specify the token in the Authorization header, so I'm having trouble.

I also don't understand how to specify the Access-Control-Request-Headers in the preflight header, as described in another questioner's thread. The reason is that the only thing that communicates to the Slack API is the browser in this case, and the only relevant source is JavaScript (React / Next.js to be exact)!

---

After that, I found preflight response from Slack API as follows;

```json
access-control-allow-headers: slack-route, x-slack-version-ts, x-b3-traceid, x-b3-spanid, x-b3-parentspanid, x-b3-sampled, x-b3-flags
```

As I thought, I understand that Authorization is not allowed because it is not included as a value. So the question is how to solve it.

[image]

---

Furthermore, I found out later that the preflight request from the browser properly declared that it wanted to use Authorization as an actual request header. However, the preflight response did not contain the value.

[image]

Comment: https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages says, _"Tokens should be passed as an HTTP Authorization header or alternatively, as a POST parameter."_ - so did you try the latter?

Comment: You're certainly right, and I haven't tried it. Now that you mention it, I realize that it is safe to include it as a parameter in GET requests as well? I can try it, so I will try it.

Comment: Oh, right, the method is supposed to be GET, not sure why they would mention POST in that very place then.

Comment: I just tried it and the CORS error was resolved, but the Slack API side didn't seem to recognize it as a parameter. Here is the actual response.

{ok: false, error: 'not_authed'}

Comment: Wait, the part I just fixed might be wrong.

Comment: @CBroe I modified my source slightly, then I got this error.

Comment: {
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_auth"
}

So I think, there is still another problem though, thanks to you, the original problem was solved??

Comment: Looks like removing the header fixed the CORS issue, but now the `invalid_auth` indicates that it probably doesn't see your token any more (unless your token was not actually valid, we can't tell.) As the documentation says POST parameter, I don't know if that means it would also accept it via GET.

Comment: But if you need to make a GET request, and can only pass the token via header - then you could only use this API via a server-side proxy, and not directly from the client side - because the headers allowing this CORS request to happen, must be issued by the Slack API. Might perhaps make sense to reach out to their support, and ask about the issue.

Comment: On the Slack API side, the token itself seems to be visible. I looked at the error pattern on the official site, and it seems that if the token itself cannot be obtained, it will be `not_authed`.

Comment: This article makes me cofused.

Comment: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2020-11-no-more-tokens-in-querystrings-for-newly-created-apps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following CBroe's advice, I was able to contact the Slack help center directly, so I asked this problem. **What I found out as a result is that HTTP requests from browsers are not supported as of the end of February 2022.** Of course, they have received quite a lot of requests regarding this, so they hope to address it at some point.

This time, the browser sent Access-Control-Request-Headers:Authorization in the preflight request. But the Slack API server side did not allow the Authorization header in the request from the browser. Therefore, Authorization was not set in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the preflight response from the Slack API side.

As a result, the response from the Slack API side returned Invalid Auth, even though Authorization was added as a header when making an actual request from the browser.

Through this error, I gained a deeper understanding of HTTP requests such as CORS and preflighting, but since it is not explicitly written on the official Slack website, I left it here.

- What is Preflight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
- What is Access-Control-Allow-Header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers
- What is CORS simple request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I can't believe the amount of time I've spent just to hit this road block.

Answer (score 1):

using `token` in request body instead of `Authorization` header worked for me.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage',
  data: `text=Hi&channel=D048GGYTJUK&token=${process.env.TOKEN}`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the Authorization header to work either. However, Slack provided [this example](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2020-11-no-more-tokens-in-querystrings-for-newly-created-apps#what) for adding token authentication to the Post body following the deprecation of the query parameters method.
This worked for me to make Web API calls to Slack from the browser (for testing) so that Slack would read the token for authentication. Note, according to Slack's [best practices for security](https://api.slack.com/authentication/best-practices#slack_apps__slack-app-based-user--bot-user-tokens), user and bot tokens should be stored with care and not used in client-side Javascript:

```js
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://slack.com/api/conversations.list", {
        method: "POST",
        body: `token=${TOKEN}`, // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Server error ${res.status}`);
      } else {
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```